# Delete most recently added directory to a directory in applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm making a script to delete messages history on a my mac. I need it to delete the most recently added folder to a directory. I can delete a folder that I have the name of, but I have no idea how to get the most recently added folder to delete it. The archive folder is ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/Archive.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the folders in Finder by creation date and get the last item

```
set archivedMessages to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Containers:com.apple.iChat:Data:Library:Messages:Archive:"
tell application "Finder"
    set mostRecentChat to last item of (sort folders of folder archivedMessages by creation date)
    delete mostRecentChat
end
```